# include variable to html title

Tags: php, include, echo, title

config.php ( edited but still have same problems ):

```
<?
$judul ="my site title";
?>
```

my index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
mysql_connect($server,$login,$pass) or die("Nggak bisa koneksi");
mysql_select_db($db);
$fail = "&nbsp;";
 ?>

<title><? echo "$judul"; ?></title>
</head>
```

the result is my website title is

```
<? echo "judul; ?>
```

not like i want to...

Is there anything that I should change?
the goal is: 
I want to put some variable like footer copyright title inside `config.php` so if I need to edit it's only need to edit config.php

----edited----
by the way thank you for all answer
it is work now

i use @Tanuel comment

once again thankyou

i vote answer ( green checklist ) based on the first answer, since i use syntax from comment

Comment: you can use constants instead. `<?php define("PAGE_TITLE","mytitle");?>` and `<title><?php echo PAGE_TITLE; ?></title>`. depends on how you wanna use it.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you want as a result, and what you get currently?

Comment: already solved using @tanuel script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

config.php

```
define('title','Hello Word');
```

index.php

```
include('config.php')

`<title><?php echo  title; ?></title>`
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have a mistake in your `config.php`. You forgot `$`. Second, you `$judul` is not declared in your `index.php`. May be you must change it to `$title` after correcting `config.php`?

Comment: Upvote for explaining his problem and how to fix it, instead of offering alternative preferences.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this code

**config.php**

```
<?php
     define('title','my site title');
 ?>
```

**my index.php**

```
<?php
     session_start();
     include('config.php');
     mysql_connect($server,$login,$pass) or die("Nggak bisa koneksi");
     mysql_select_db($db);
     $fail = "&nbsp;";
 ?>

<title><?php echo title; ?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: still same result ... title is <? echo title; ?>

Answer (score 0):

In config.php, the variable declaration is incorrect. Use the below code for that.

```
<?php
$title = "Site Title";
?>
```

If your idea was to define the title as a constant, use the below code instead (on config.php)

```
<?php
define('title',"Site Title");
?>
```

In the index.php, incorrect variable is used. Use $title to get the actual title initialized in config.php (if you are using variable to get title). Use the below code on index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
mysql_connect($server,$login,$pass) or die("Nggak bisa koneksi");
mysql_select_db($db);
$fail = "&nbsp;";
 ?>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
```

If you want to use the constant instead, use the below code

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
mysql_connect($server,$login,$pass) or die("Nggak bisa koneksi");
mysql_select_db($db);
$fail = "&nbsp;";
 ?>
<head>
<title><?php echo title; ?></title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable **config.php** as **global** variable.

```
<?php
global $pageTitle;
$pageTitle = "Site Title";
?>
```

And in the index.php again you have to call it as global variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
mysql_connect($server,$login,$pass) or die("Nggak bisa koneksi");
mysql_select_db($db);
$fail = "&nbsp;";

global $pageTitle;
 ?>
<head>
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
</head>
```

If you want in multiple pages just use it like array.
In config.php

```
<?php
global $pageTitle;
$pageTitle['page1'] = "Site Title 1";
$pageTitle['page2'] = "Site Title 2";
?>
```

Comment: nothing happen still same ...

Comment: Edited the answer. In index.php code earlier it was **<? echo $pageTitle; ?>** . Now corrected. **<?php echo $pageTitle; ?>**